How to pretty format HTML in python while keeping <tr> children </tr> in 1 line?
I want to pretty print HTML while keeping <tr> children </tr> in 1 line. HTML STRING looks like html = '''<html><body><h1>hello world</h1><table><tr><td>1 STRING</td><td>2 STRING</td><td>3 STRING</td></tr></table></body></html>'''
I tried to solve the problem with bs4's prettify, but it isn't giving correct result.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Original HTML string
html = '''<html><body><h1>hello world</h1><table><tr><td>1 STRING</td><td>2 STRING</td><td>3 STRING</td></tr></table></body></html>'''
</tr></table></body></html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

prettified_html = soup.prettify()

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    
    inline_tr = f"<tr>{''.join(str(td) for td in tr.find_all('td'))}</tr>"
    
    prettified_html = prettified_html.replace(str(tr), inline_tr)


print(prettified_html)

Ouptut:
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>
   hello world
  </h1>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     1 STRING
    </td>
    <td>
     2 STRING
    </td>
    <td>
     3 STRING
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>

Wanted output:
<!-- HTML-->
<tr><td>1 STRING</td><td>2 STRING</td><td>3 STRING</td></tr>
<!--HTML-->

I'm open to using any python packages to solve the problem.

Just use regex to remove the '/n' between the <tr> and </tr> tags
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

# Original HTML string
html = '''<html><body><h1>hello world</h1><table><tr><td>1 STRING</td><td>2 STRING</td><td>3 STRING</td></tr></table></body></html>
</tr></table></body></html>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

prettified_html = soup.prettify()

def remove_newlines_in_tr(match):
    tr_content = match.group(0)

    lines = tr_content.split('\n')
    lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    tr_content = ''.join(lines)
    return tr_content

pattern = re.compile(r'<tr>.*?</tr>', re.DOTALL)

html_inline_tr = pattern.sub(remove_newlines_in_tr, prettified_html)

print(html_inline_tr)


thanks, I had gotten the ans on my own through RegEx too, so this is the accepted ans
